# How to design a spring boot application that can process 1k requests a second

Tags: spring, httpclient, software-design, completable-future

I have a rest controller which accepts post requests and returns the statuses of whether the operations are successfull or not. It works fine for 100 requests per second as I have multiple operations underlying it which at the end send the response.

There could be hundreds of users trying to send the requests to the controller, thereby its all done using a completable future and http Async invoker. The problem happens when there are a 1000 requests per second and then the controller threads are exhausted as there are already multiple thread processing multiple  requests and all are waiting for there future to be complete and then sending the response.

How can I make my rest controller be able to handle 1000 requests per Second without breaking.

Comment: in how many servers application is running?

Comment: Just one. Increasing the instance is not an option.

Comment: Then increase tomcat web container threads with cpu and memory

Comment: Increasing threads is again not scalable.

Comment: Being scalable means that increasing the number of threads or the number of servers will also increase the number of concurrent requests that can be handled. By refusing to increase anything, you simply refuse to scale, WebFlux was designed to handle large number of concurrent requests witha small number of threads, but is webflux suited to what your app is doing? We have no idea because we don't know anyting about it.

Answer (score 3):

> there are already multiple thread processing multiple requests and all are waiting for there future to be complete and then sending the response.

You can actually make you controllers asynchronous by making them return a `CompletableFuture`. Just chain the calls on the `CompletableFuture` returned by your service to convert them into a an appropriate response instead of using `get()` or `join()`:

```
@RequestMapping
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<…>> processRequest() {
    return myService.getStatusFuture()
                    .thenApply(status -> convertToResponseEntity(status));
}
```

Of course for this to work properly you should have a truly asynchronous service. If you are using `@Async` or submitting tasks with `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()`, this will just move the problem from the HTTP threadpool to another threadpool.

Comment: but i believe http thread need to wait for the response from controller right? what if 200 web requests are fired at once?

Comment: No, if you do it like this, Spring takes care of it and frees the HTTP thread, it can thus pick another request.

Comment: No, it will be the chained calls on the `CompletableFuture` that will take care of it, however you have to guarantee that the initial future will eventually be completed (it could be with an exception) otherwise no response will be sent.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the servlet server you are using. In the **application.properties** file, you can use the **server.*** properties to set the parameters you need.

In this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) you can find these properties under the *EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION* section. If you are using the default tomcat embedded server, check out the **server.tomcat.*** properties. Especially the **server.tomcat.accept-count**, **server.tomcat.max-connections** and **server.tomcat.max-threads** properties.

Comment: The problem is that the spring boot application threads are exhausted thereby its sending the too many concurrent requests . My server settings for incoming connection are maxed out.  What would be a better design to handle so many requests without exhausting the threads assuming that each request needs some time of cpu.